# Разбиение данных на части заданного размера при записи

Tags: python

Пишу программу, которая разбивает текст на части по 10000 символов и записывает эти символы в файл.

Как сделать, чтобы автоматически создавались новые файлы и в них записывалось 10000 символов. Например, у меня текст в 40000 символов, я хочу его разбить на 4 файла по 10000 символов. Помогите, пожалуйста.
вот код:

```
count = 1
sim_count = 1
temp_sim = ""
with open("5815016.txt", "r") as file:
    temp = file.read()
for simvol in temp:
    temp_sim += simvol
    str(count)
    if sim_count >= 10000:
        with open("result/part.txt", "w") as file_write:
            file_write.write(temp_sim)
    count += 1
    sim_count += 1
```

Comment: sim_count сравнивается в цикле и никогда не сбрасывается, путь к файлу part один и тот же для каждой части

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант считать количество символов, и проверять, если оно кратно 10000, то создавать новый файл, и к названию прибавлять номер( я номером сделал результат деления количества символов на 10000), и по нужному срезу записывать строку в файл

```
count = 0
for simvol in temp:
    if count % 10000 == 0:
        with open("part.txt" + str(count // 10000), "w") as file_write:
                file_write.write(temp[count - 10000:count])
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так

```py
def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

with open("5815016.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks(text, 10000)):
    with open("result\\part-{}.txt".format(i), "w") as f:
        f.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного переработал код, вот что получилось:

```py
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()


slices = []
count = 0
for i in range(1,len(data)//10000 + 1):
    slices.append([count, i*10000])
    count = i*10000

slices.append([count, len(data)+1])
for start, end in slices:
    with open(f"{start}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(data[start:end])
```

Я работал с тестовым файлом, который содержит 188890 символов

```py
>>> len(data)
188890
```

Далее я разбил длину на участки кратные 10000 и поместил в список `slices`, в конец которого поместил остаток символов 8890

```py
>>> slices 
[[0, 10000], [10000, 20000], [20000, 30000], [30000, 40000], [40000, 50000], [50000, 60000], [60000, 70000], [70000, 80000], [80000, 90000], [90000, 100000], [100000, 110000], [110000, 120000], [120000, 130000], [130000, 140000], [140000, 150000], [150000, 160000], [160000, 170000], [170000, 180000], [180000, 188890]]
```

И в конце пробегаюсь по этому листу, который определяет промежутки для нужных файлов и сохраняю срезы в файлы